# Files are not downloaded in the folders having names extracted from the url

Tags: bash, sed

ok, I have these urls

```
https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/911-omicidio-al-telefono/stagione-1-appesa-a-un-filo
https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/avamposti-dispacci-dal-confine/stagione-1-cerignola
https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/belle-da-morire/stagione-1-bellezza-stalking
```

I try to create these folder with these names

```
911-omicidio-al-telefono
avamposti-dispacci-dal-confine
belle-da-morire
```

extracting the name from urls

for example I would like the file from the url

`https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/911-omicidio-al-telefono/stagione-1-appesa-a-un-filo`

to download directly inside the folder name extracted from the url

```
911-omicidio-al-telefono
```

but this seems problematic because no folder names are extracted and each file is downloaded outside their folderURL name

To solve this problem I created a `script.sh` with this code

```
 #!/bin/bash

# Extract the folder name from the URL
url=$1
folder_name=$(echo $url | cut -d "/" -f6)


echo "folder_name: $folder_name"

if [[ "$folder_name" == "NA" ]]
then
    echo "Can't extract folder name from $url"
    exit
fi

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$folder_name"


echo "file_path: $file_path"

# Download the video and audio files
ffmpeg -i "$file_path.fdash-video=6157520.mp4" -i "$file_path.fdash-audio_eng=160000.m4a" -c copy "$file_path.mp4"

# Move the file to the correct folder and rename it with .mp4 extension
mv "$file_path.mp4" "$folder_name/$file_path.mp4"
```

and then from bash terminal I call it in this way

```
yt-dlp --referer "https://ppppppppppp.com/" --add-header "Cookie:COOKIE" --batch-file links_da_scaricare.txt -o '%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --exec "~/script.sh {}"
```

I use cygwin and script.sh is in C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator but I test also with ubuntu and problem is the same: it creates a folder called `NA` and download inside that folder.

All files are downloaded in the same `NA` folder and not in their folders, in other word are not downloaded in the folders having names extracted from the url from which the files are downloaded

**EDIT**

I use SpellCheck and I fix code of script.sh and now I haven't issues

```
#!/bin/bash

url=$1
file_path=$2
# Extract the folder name from the URL
folder_name=$(echo "$url" | cut -d "/" -f4)
echo "folder_name: $folder_name"
# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$folder_name"
echo "The script is running and creating folder: $folder_name" > ~/script.log
# Move the file to the correct folder and rename it with .mp4 extension
mv "$file_path" "$folder_name/$folder_name.mp4"
```

but when I try to run this command from Cygwin terminal

`yt-dlp --referer "https://pppppppppp.com" --add-header "Cookie:COOKIE" --batch-file links_da_scaricare.txt -o '%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --exec "C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\script.sh {} $file_path"`

NA folder is still created and no other folders are created so files are downloaded only into NA and not in their folders

Comment: You are not setting the variable `file_path` in your program.  You want to minimize your problem (is the issue with caller or script; if script caller is irrelevant).

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus I fix and I have no issue with this code `"#!/bin/bash

url=$1
file_path=$2

# Extract the folder name from the URL
folder_name=$(echo "$url" | cut -d "/" -f4)

echo "folder_name: $folder_name"

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "$folder_name"

echo "The script is running and creating folder: $folder_name" >> /tmp/script.log

# Move the file to the correct folder and rename it with .mp4 extension
mv "$file_path" "$folder_name/$folder_name.mp4"`

Comment: @AllanWind When I try to run it with `yt-dlp --referer "https://pppppppppp.com" --add-header "Cookie:COOKIE" --batch-file links_da_scaricare.txt -o '%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' --exec "C:\cygwin64\home\Administrator\script.sh {} $file_path"` is still `NA` folder created and no other folders are created so files are downloaded only into NA

Comment: @user3520363 You edit your question with clarifications instead of using comments.

Comment: @AllanWind ok, done, you can see question edited

Comment: @user3520363 You don't want to preserve history of your question (the system already does that), just edit to ensure it's explains the problem as clear as possible.

Comment: Can you `cd` to each target folder in your script, then run the downloader from there?

Comment: @user3520363 If the folder NA is being created this means folder_name is "NA".  When I use the first example from your list "https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/911-omicidio-al-telefono/stagione-1-appesa-a-un-filo" the folder name is "it" which is the 4th field separated with '/'.  If the value is "NA" then your input is not what you claim is.  We don't know anything about your caller script.  You use a variable "$file_path" in the exec.  This implies you run the script as a shell script.  We don't know that.

Comment: @user3520363 If your script accepts a path in the -o option, I suggest run a script creates the folder then call `yt-dlp` to download to download it directly into the right folder.

Comment: Please read the section `TEMPLATE` in man yt-dlp, this will most probably obviate the need to call --exec. Also note that you are using yt-dlp in batch mode and your output template includes `%(playlist)s` maybe the reason for `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75088710/files-are-not-downloaded-in-the-folders-having-names-extracted-from-the-url

# Extract the folder name from the URL
#url=$1
url="https://www.ppppppppppp.com/it/yyyy/911-omicidio-al-telefono/stagione-1-appesa-a-un-filo"

folder_name=$(echo $url | cut -d "/" -f6 )

### Missing
if [ "${folder_name}" = "" ] ; then  folder_name="NA" ; fi

echo "folder_name: $folder_name"

if [[ "$folder_name" == "NA" ]]
then
    echo "Can't extract folder name from $url"
    exit
fi

### Missing
file_path="$(pwd)/${folder_name}"

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p "${file_path}"

echo "file_path: ${file_path}"

download="arbitrary_name"
wget -O "${file_path}/${download}" "${url}"

# Download the video and audio files
ffmpeg -i "${file_path}/${download}.fdash-video=6157520.mp4" -i "${file_path}/${download}.fdash-audio_eng=160000.m4a" -c copy "${file_path}/${download}.mp4"
```

Some of that can't be verified by myself, because I don't have an account to access primevideo, at

```
https://www.primevideo.com/detail/0S0UEN2OCD7CTY5TQF3N6KB1ET/ref=atv_dp_season_select_s1
```

Also, I don't think you can download the two, video and audio, separately.

Comment: Look [HERE](https://i.imgur.com/sRY1r8J.gif) and then [HERE](https://pastebin.com/raw/uWxGhexX) please and then you can test using my cookie. Problem is about folder name because it make folder in bad location with bad name and files are not downloaded in its own folder whose name must first be extracted from the url from which the file comes and from which it will be downloaded. So in my case the folders `mortal-city` and `il-boss-delle-cerimonie` have to be created first and then the files have to be downloaded exactly in the respective folder, not in a single folder `C:\cygwin64\home\`